# How to remove JSON data array (and keep its content) in Python

Tags: python, json

I am programming a tool with the Roblox API. My code to request data from Roblox's API is below, it stores it and uses it later (not related to this issue)

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError
import json

try:
    response = requests.get('https://groups.roblox.com/v2/groups?groupIds=10491230') # example random group
    response.raise_for_status()
    # access JSOn content
    json1 = response.json()
    print(json1)

except HTTPError as http_err:
    print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')
except Exception as err:
    print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')
```

The output is below (value of json1)

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "description": "string",
      "owner": {
        "id": 0,
        "type": "User",
        "name": "string"
      },
      "memberCount": 0,
      "created": "2022-05-09T16:16:38.105Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Since I need to parse and interact with the data in the data[] array, I need to remove it, so the output would be simular to the output below.

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "owner": {
    "id": 0,
    "type": "User",
    "name": "string"
  },
  "memberCount": 0,
  "created": "2022-05-09T16:16:38.105Z"
}
```

How would I remove the data[] part, but keep the data inside? I tried replace() and JSON parsing, but have no idea how to start.

Language: Python

Thanks!

API documentation is available at https://groups.roblox.com/docs#!/Groups/get_v2_groups

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
json1 = response.json()["data"]
```

Comment: Well, I tried it and I get the output of "Other error occurred: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" when I try to access the data with `print(json1["name"])`

Comment: It returns out the output: {'data': [{'id': 0, 'name': 'test', 'description': 'test', 'owner': {'id': 0, 'type': 'User'}, 'created': '2021-04-23T21:31:27.993Z'}]}

Comment: Check out the updated code please, not sure if something else is wrong...

Comment: Here is the code i ran (difference only): `json1 = response.json()["data"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can store content inside data array in another variable

```
data = json1["data"][0]
```

or if you want the whole array

```
data = json1["data"]
```

Comment: Same thing as last time, I get the output of `Other error occurred: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` when trying to print a specific piece of the json out with `print(data["name"])`

Comment: I am getting the desired output. `data["name"]` => prints the name from the data

Comment: Check out the updated code please, not sure if something else is wrong...

Comment: Even the updated code works perfectly on my machine with the additions from the answer.

Comment: What output are you getting? Still getting the errors with whatever changes made. Tried running on both Linux and Windows

Comment: `print(json1["data"][0])` => `{'id': 10491230, 'name': 'BlueBunnyYT (Clube)', 'description': 'My channel was seleted', 'owner': {'id': 2480457169, 'type': 'User'}, 'created': '2021-04-23T21:31:27.993Z'}`